# ArrayBufferView Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1

Tags: javascript, python, binary, websocket, arraybuffer

I send binary data over websocket from python server:

```
data = struct.pack('!BI', 2, 1)
channel.send(channel.BINARY, data)
```

Data sending works fine.
On client side javascript gets it like this:

```
onbinarydata: function(data) {
    alert(data.byteLength);
    >> 5
    var array = new Uint8Array(data,0,1);
    alert(array[0]);
    >> 2
    var array2 = new Uint32Array(data,1,5);
    >> Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1
    alert(array2[0]);
```

How can this happen?
Byte length minus byte offset is 4, and BYTY_ELEMENT_SIZE is also 4.
First value is read without problems, but next always raise error, whatever type it is.
Even if I only set byte offset like this

```
var array2 = new Uint32Array(data,1);
```

there is an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cannot create int32/uint32 array with offset not divisible by 4. The same for int16/uint16 and 2.

This is the limitation of CPU architecture.

Let those 2 variables would be `A:Uint16` and `B:Uint8`. You can map them onto bytes with different methods:

- `BBAA` (put value B into Uint16)
- `0BAA` / `B0AA` (skip 1 byte for alignment)
- `AAB` (reorder for alignment).

If you don't want to think about big-/little-endiad, reordering and other stuff... i.e. if you still want to put variables into bytes as `BAA` for some reason, then use the following idea:

For each not-aligned variable put into corresponding size buffer and copy it byte-by-byte.
If misalign is 2 bytes, then copy may be made by pair of bytes.

```
var array = new Uint8Array(data,0,1);
alert(array);

var array2 = new Uint8Array(data,1,5);
var abuf2 = new ArrayBuffer(4);
var abuf2_8 = new Uint8Array(abuf2);
// using `subarray` won't help, cause it doesn't create a copy like `slice`
// and the same data will have the same inconsistent memory alignment
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) abuf2_8[i] = array2[i];
var abuf2_32 = new Uint32Array(abuf2);
alert(abuf2_32[0]);
```

BTW There's some ready code for packing/unpacking in js:

- [mine](http://kirilloid.ru/sc2replay/packer.js)
- [phpjs](http://phpjs.org/functions/pack:880)

which are similar to [php pack](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pack.php)

My code may be more interesting to you, cause there're 2 classes: to pack into binary string and to pack into arraybuffer.

Comment: Does it mean that I can't send in one frame two values with different type, like Uint8 and Uint16? Or should I use slice on arraybuffer, but this is Big-endian so i have to slice begginig from last byte of array?

Comment: Why? Let those 2 variables would be `A:Uint16` and `B:Uint8`. You can map them onto bytes with different methods: `BBAA` (put value B into Uint16), `0BAA` / `B0AA` (skip 1 byte for alignment), `AAB` (reorder for alignment)

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I thought about it too, but it seemed for me a bit strange to do it this way.

Comment: I've updated by answer with solution in comment as well as another option.

Comment: Fortunately order of values is defined by me so I can use the first method, it will be faster for sure, but thanks for answer!